# Unable to find and run a script on a new SSD

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssd

I have just installed a new SSD on my machine as I was having storage issues. I am looking run a script (Nethermind for the ETH 1 Execution layer) and store the data on this SSD.

New SSD disk image:

[image: New SSD DISK Images]

I am new to Ubuntu, so I imagine there is a simple fix for this issue, but I am clearly an ape and I am not able to run the nethermind.runner script in terminal. I find it in the LS command, but when I attempt to run it, my result is:

```
jknuc@JKNUC:/mnt/nvme0n1p1/ExecutionLayer$ ./nethermind.runner
bash: ./nethermind.runner: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Result from ls showing files:

[image: Result from ls showing files]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: try to run `./nethermind --config <your node>`

Answer (score 2):

Linux files are case sensitive.

You have `Nethermind.Runner` file, but trying to run `nethermind.runner`.

SSD is unrelated.